# Some basic questions about Processor and OS?

Tags: windows-7, cpu

I need an explanation, I have a computer with a processor :

> Intel Core i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40 Ghz 3.40 Ghz

---

1. Does this mean I have two processors with a clock rate 3.40 Ghz each ??
2. Is this a Core Duo ? or a better version of it Core i7 ? but there is two cores, right ?.

---

3. I have *Windows 7 Professionnel Service Pack 1* activated. Does this mean  I can have the update to *Pack 3* for free ? how to do that ?
4. The Operating system installed is *32bits* ? but I have two CPU , does this mean I can use OS in *64bits* ? do I have to install a new Windows ??

---

And also :

- `wmic os get osarchitecture` respond with `32bits`.
- `wmic computersystem get numberofprocessors` respond `1 processor`
- `wmic computersystem get numberoflogicalprocessors` respond `8`

Comment: You have a single processor, the i7-3770 and it is 4 generations newer then the Core Duo.  There isn't a Service Pack 3 for Windows 7, there isn't a Service Pack 2 for Windows 7 either.  The i7-3770 is a 64-bit processor.  You have a single processor which has 4 physical cores and supports hyperthreading which means you have an additional 4 virtual cores.  You are running a 32-bit installation of Windows currently.

Comment: These should be split into multiple questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean I have two processors with a clock rate 3.40 Ghz each
>   ??

From the line it is hard to say that you have two processors. Simple version to find out: open it up and look if you have two processors. If this line is from windows then you (most probably) have only one processor. Intel provied a nice explanation why there are two frequencies shown:
http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technical-specifications/processor-frequency-display-mismatch-windows-advisory.pdf
(short story: the first is part of the name, the second is determined by Windows)

To get details about your CPU I reccomend [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).

> Is this a Core Duo ? or a better version of it Core i7 ? but there is
>   two cores, right ?.

First of all [ask Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Intel%20Core%20i7-3770%20CPU%20%40%203.40%20Ghz%203.40%20Ghz). From the first result you get: `# of Cores: 4`
So you have 4 cores.

> I have Windows 7 Professionnel Service Pack 1 activated. Does this
>   mean I can have the update to Pack 3 for free ? how to do that ?

There is no SP3 for Win7.

> The Operating system installed is 32bits ? but I have two CPU , does
>   this mean I can use OS in 64bits ?

You can use 64bit OS, but this has nothing to do with having 2 CPUs. The CPU you have supports 64bit.

> do I have to install a new Windows ??

No, the 32bit version will work as well. Performance might be different, and if you have more than 4 GB of RAM you can not use them with 32bit Windows.

Comment: Sorry, I should have googled that ... but I still have small basic question : is the word "core" does not mean "processor" ??

Comment: and also, CPU-Z is great. It shows me that I have One Processor, 4 Cores and 8 Threads.

Comment: There’s only one CPU because this CPU can only work standalone. @OSryx: Essentially, a 4-core CPU is 4 processors in one unit (“socket”). Of course it’s a little more complicated, but you need not worry about that.

Answer (score 3):

1. run `wmic computersystem get numberofprocessors,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors/Format:List` in the Command Prompt to find The Core Count.
2. According to Intel ARK, you have 4 cores and 8 threads and the processor is 64-bit, it's also a 3rd gen core i7
3. There is no SP3 for Windows 7, only SP1. Don't bother trying to find SP3 for Windows 6.1 (Windows 7)
4. Run `wmic os get osarchitecture` to Find the type of OS you have. You have 4 Cores with Intel-HT (Hyper Threading), meaning 8 **Logical** Processors. Yes you do need to install a fresh copy of Windows 7 with all the drivers if you have 32-bit and want to be 64-bit.

Comment: wmic os get osarchitecture donne 32bits !! ?

Comment: Then if you have more than 4GB RAM, you are free to upgrade to 64 bit

Comment: I have exactly 4 Gb of DDR3 memory.

Comment: Then feel free to reinstall Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

**1:-** The two frequencies refer to the rated speed and the actual speed, which in most cases is the same, unless you overclock or have [Intel Turbo Boost](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html) active.

**2:-** [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/65719/Intel-Core-i7-3770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) states that your PC is a 4 core CPU with an additional 4 virtual [Hyperthreaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) cores. Which means you have 4 cores, each with two threads, equally a total of 8 threads.

**3:-** [There is no Service Pack Three](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/service-packs-download#sptabs=win7).

**4:-** 32bit or 64bit depends on what version was installed. You could have the best processor in the world but if you have a 32bit OS, you are limited by that. Even Dual Logical CPU systems cannot change a 32bit system to a 64bit.
On that note, upgrade your system to 64bit. It pains me to see a powerful CPU like a 3rd Gen i7 in a 32bit system. If ever you needed more than 4GB of RAM, you will not be able to address any more than 3.5(ish)GB and with that processor, you should be looking to future proof and get the most out of it.
A new W7 install will be necessary.

Comment: Also, please Google before asking on here. I don't mean to offend but this is some elementary stuff that will have been answered before.

Comment: 32bit OS won't make 64bit CPU any slower (in fact for some workloads it will be faster). And since we have PAE the system limit is 64 GB (with 4 GB for single application).

Answer (score 0):

32bit Windows does not affect only the CPU, but the RAM as well if you have more than 4 GB. As [@TD.512](https://superuser.com/a/915132/87805) I recommend you to upgrade to 64bit OS.